# To transfer file from pc to android device via usb

Tags: android, sockets, usb, httpurlconnection

I want to transfer a file from my pc's particular port to android device over USB programmatically. Which technique is best for this mode of transfer among the following :

1. Sockets
2. HttpUrlConnection.

If it is possible through `HttpUrlConnection` means how to implement this?

Comment: Socket connection will be better one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To transfer file from pc to android device via USB **Socket Communication** is best approach.

You have to do some additional step of port forwarding on which the Socket Communication establish.

Look at Tutorial https://github.com/user370305/Android-USB-Communication.

Comment: @Pals - Where is my +1? :)

Comment: Its there, havent you seen :P

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Is it possible to achieve this using HttpUrlConnection?