# Communication between android app and pc application through USB

Tags: android

I have my android tablet connected to windows pc machine through USB cable. I don't have internet connection.

I need a solution to establish a connection and transfer files from pc to android app. I think we can use Android open accessories in accessory mode. Is there a better solution to solve this problem or is android open accessories the right solution. What are the shortcomings of this solution ?

Comment: You transfer files using USB... or LAN network connection... You don't need internet

Comment: I assume you want to make this possible via code then follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129437/to-transfer-file-from-pc-to-android-device-via-usb
Otherwise you can just transfer files normally through windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

you should install the drivers for your tablet and to transfer the files using usb. Your android tablet tablet might not be recognized without drivers. Also you should store the files inside `download` folder to be easily visible by the pc.